# Não consigo utilizar o a biblioteca chatterbot python

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatterbot

Estou tentando criar um bot para fins pessoais então tentei instalar o chatterbot do python porém ao tentar o rodar o código ele acusa um erro já tentei instalar outras versões do Python procurei em forums mas não encontrei ninguém que tinha passado por isso tbm, o código é bem simples:

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
chatbot = ChatBot("Ron Obvious")
conversation = [
    "Hello",
    "Hi there!",
    "How are you doing?",
    "I'm doing great.",
    "That is good to hear",
    "Thank you.",
    "You're welcome."
]

trainer = ListTrainer(chatbot)

trainer.train(conversation)
response = chatbot.get_response("Good morning!")
print(response)
```

Quando rodo o coidigo ele devolve o seguinte error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Leticia\Desktop\junior\Programação\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from chatterbot import ChatBot
  File "C:\Users\Leticia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .chatterbot import ChatBot
  File "C:\Users\Leticia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\chatterbot.py", line 2, in <module>
    from chatterbot.storage import StorageAdapter
  File "C:\Users\Leticia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\storage\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from chatterbot.storage.storage_adapter import StorageAdapter
  File "C:\Users\Leticia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\storage\storage_adapter.py", line 3, in <module>
    from chatterbot.tagging import PosHypernymTagger
  File "C:\Users\Leticia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\tagging.py", line 8, in <module>
    import spacy
  File "C:\Users\Leticia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .cli.info import info as cli_info
  File "C:\Users\Leticia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .train import train  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Users\Leticia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\train.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ..gold import GoldCorpus
  File "strings.pxd", line 23, in init spacy.gold
ImportError: DLL load failed: Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.
```

Atualmente estou o utilizando o python 3.7 porém o mesmo erro ocorre no 3.6 e 3.8 utilizo o windows 10 64 bits e o python foi instalado diretamente pelo site oficial.

Answer (score 0):

A IDE faz a busca pelo módulo nesses endereços locais que estao em "file ...". Provavelmente vc pode ter feita a instalação do módulo chatterbot em uma outra pasta que nao é essa onde a IDE esta indo procurar. Por esse motivo, ela acusa o erro de nao ter
encontrado o módulo no seu computador.
Se for isso mesmo, pega a pasta onde vc instalou o chatterbot e recorta ela para esse endereço que a IDE esta procurando.
Esse endereço é a pasta que contém o interpretador python, se o módulo nao estiver na mesma pasta que o interpretador, o módulo nao é encontrado.
Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Tudo esta instalado na mesma pasta por favor se puder me ajudar não sei oq eu faço.